# Why does deadlock occur when using ManualResetEvent and asynchronous method in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mutex

This is a question I faced in WPF.NET. To illustrate the problem, let us take a look at the class below :

```
public class TaskRunnerWithProgressFeedback(){
     ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
     public void RunTask(Action action) {
        _event.Reset();
        //Display loading screen
        RunAsync(action);
        Console.WriteLine("Load completed.");
        //Hide loading screen
        _event.WaitOne();
    }

    private async void RunAsync(Action action) {
        await Task.Run(() => action.Invoke());
        _event.Set();
    }
}
```

So I have this class here, and I will call the `RunTask` method from a UI thread.
For example :

```cs
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var x = new TaskRunnerWithProgressFeedback();
    x.RunTask(()=>{ /*Some time-consuming action*/ });
}
```

And when Button1 is clicked, the whole program runs into a deadlocked situation. Do you have any explanation for this situation?

*Foot note : I need the `TaskRunnerWithProgressFeedback` class for me to do behavioral testing. I'm not using `BackgroundWorker` because it will break those tests.*

Comment: Where is `WaitOne()`?

Comment: Don't call an `async` method without `await`. And don't use `async void` methods anywhere except event handlers.

Comment: Sinatr sorry, that was an accident, just added it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `_event.Set()` is supposed to be executed on the UI thread once the `Task` that you create in the `RunAsync` method has completed.

The deadlock occurs if you call `_event.WaitOne()` on the UI thread before that task has completed.

Because then the UI threads waits for the `ManualResetEvent` to be set but it never will be because the code that calls the `Set()` method cannot be executed on the UI thread because it is blocked by the `WaitOne()` call.

This is basically how `async`/`await` works.  The `async` method runs synchronously until it hits and `await`, and then return to the caller. The context (the dispatcher thread in this case) is captured and the remainder of the `async` method is then executed back on the same dispatcher/UI thread that the `async` method was invoked on once the awaited method has completed.

But the remainder of the method can of course not be executed until the context thread is free. And in this case it never will be because it waits for the remainder of the `async` method to call `Set()` => Deadlock.

Comment: This is a great description of the problem. To fix it, you can use `AsyncManualResetEvent` from [my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx)